# Working with laravel collection methods on a Shopping Cart

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is how my collection looks like right now.

```
[{"id":"1","quantity":1},{"id":"2","quantity":1}]
```

What can I do to match the `id` and change the `quantity` to 2. This is for a shopping cart.

So in the end it would look like this if we found a item already in cart.

```
[{"id":"1","quantity":2},{"id":"2","quantity":1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use collection's `transform` method. It iterates over the items in the collection, allowing you to change values.

Let's say your collection of objects is stored in `$someCollection`. You could do this:

```
$someCollection->transform(function ($item, $key) use ($id) {
    if ($item->id == $id) {
       $item->quantity++;
    }
    return $item;
});
```

This will increase the quantity by one for the item with the id that you pass in $id

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-transform

Answer (score 0):

use [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-transform) on cart collection.

```
$id = 1;
$cart->transform(function ($item) use ($id) {
    if ($item['id'] == $id) {
        $item['q']++;
    }
    return $item;
});
```